# Use cURL to login to website using Google Credentials

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Is it possible to login to a website via cURL using your Google Credentials (Provided "Log in using Google" is available)?

I tried to save my cookies and load them into cURL. This works but only for about a day and then the cookies expire. Is there a way to just have it login as me if I explicitly give it my Google credentials? This is going to be used in tandem with a cron job to pull some data at specific times of the day.

Edit: Some people are confused as to what I am asking. The website i want to pull data from has option of "Login via Google" already. I want to explicitly input my Google credentials to have it login.

Edit2: For the sake of example, lets say you want to login to Stackoverflow using cURL with just your Google Account credentials.

Comment: Interesting question, do you mean to the login with google plugin, like in stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean

Comment: Does the current login you are using have a client_id and client secret?  are you saving the refreshToken returned by it?  if so they you can use that to access google via cURL.

Comment: @DaImTo I am only seeing a client_id.

Comment: @Bijan Did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking for the exact same functionality you describe here.

Comment: No. The website had an alternative login function where i could just explicitly use a login and password instead of a google account